# Removing array brackets in the ansible variable result

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I have an issue about removing the array brackets in the output.  I need the output without the array brackets so that i can pass the result in the rest api code.  I have an example listed here below.  I would like to group each set with the name and nicknames associated with that name.  I was able to group the nicknames for each host but the result has brackets which I am trying to remove.

```
 name: Set Global Vars
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    msg: [
        {
            "name": "abcdsto1",
            "portnames": [
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto1p1",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec2ec9a",
                    "type": "fc"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto1p2",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec2ec9b",
                    "type": "fc"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto1p3",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec2ec3a",
                    "type": "fc"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto1p4",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec2ec3b",
                    "type": "fc"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "abcdsto2",
            "portnames": [
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto2p1",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec2ec06",
                    "type": "fc"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto2p2",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec2ec07",
                    "type": "fc"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto2p3",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec2ec64",
                    "type": "fc"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto2p4",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec2ec65",
                    "type": "fc"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "abcdsto3",
            "portnames": [
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto3p1",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec43f20",
                    "type": "fc"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto3p2",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec43f21",
                    "type": "fc"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto3p3",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec43f30",
                    "type": "fc"
                },
                {
                    "nickname": "abcdsto3p4",
                    "port": "4353000e1ec43f31",
                    "type": "fc"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  tasks:    
    - name: print json file
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.portnames | community.general.json_query('[*].nickname') }}"
      loop: "{{ msg }}"
```

```
TASK [print json file] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'abcdsto1', 'portnames': [{'nickname': 'abcdsto1p1', 'port': '4353000e1ec2ec9a', 'type': 'fc'}, {'nickname': 'abcdsto1p2', 'port': '4353000e1ec2ec9b', 'type': 'fc'}, {'nickname': 'abcdsto1p3', 'port': '4353000e1ec2ec3a', 'type': 'fc'}, {'nickname': 'abcdsto1p4', 'port': '4353000e1ec2ec3b', 'type': 'fc'}]}) => {
    "msg": [
        "abcdsto1p1",
        "abcdsto1p2",
        "abcdsto1p3",
        "abcdsto1p4"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'abcdsto2', 'portnames': [{'nickname': 'abcdsto2p1', 'port': '4353000e1ec2ec06', 'type': 'fc'}, {'nickname': 'abcdsto2p2', 'port': '4353000e1ec2ec07', 'type': 'fc'}, {'nickname': 'abcdsto2p3', 'port': '4353000e1ec2ec64', 'type': 'fc'}, {'nickname': 'abcdsto2p4', 'port': '4353000e1ec2ec65', 'type': 'fc'}]}) => {
    "msg": [
        "abcdsto2p1",
        "abcdsto2p2",
        "abcdsto2p3",
        "abcdsto2p4"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'abcdsto3', 'portnames': [{'nickname': 'abcdsto3p1', 'port': '4353000e1ec43f20', 'type': 'fc'}, {'nickname': 'abcdsto3p2', 'port': '4353000e1ec43f21', 'type': 'fc'}, {'nickname': 'abcdsto3p3', 'port': '4353000e1ec43f30', 'type': 'fc'}, {'nickname': 'abcdsto3p4', 'port': '4353000e1ec43f31', 'type': 'fc'}]}) => {
    "msg": [
        "abcdsto3p1",
        "abcdsto3p2",
        "abcdsto3p3",
        "abcdsto3p4"
    ]
}
```

But I need the result to be

```
msg: abcdsto1p1,abcdsto1p2,abcdsto1p3,abcdsto1p4

msg: abcdsto2p1,abcdsto2p2,abcdsto2p3,abcdsto2p4

msg: abcdsto3p1,abcdsto3p2,abcdsto3p3,abcdsto3p4
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `msg: "{{ item.portnames | community.general.json_query('[*].nickname') | join(',') }}"`> https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this same issue.  The `join` filter will work here to extract it from being pack into an array.

Before the join this is what I was using

```
{%- set _ = nodes.append(hostvars[server]['node_id']
```

this is what was being returned, even though it was coming form a valid `list` item.

```
- - 63dbc56c-8abb-a9e1-b604-71b4a7cf698e
```

If you then try to strip the extra hyphen using replace() filter, it will pack it into an array

```
| replace('-', '')
```

```
 - '[''63dbc56c-8abb-a9e1-b604-71b4a7cf698e'']'
```

When filtering with `join()` it, it essentially gets casted to a string.  If you have only one item in the array, then its just one string in your `list`.

```
{%- set _ = nodes.append(hostvars[server]['node_id'] | join(',') ) -%}\
```

The `list` data comes back cleaner, as expected

```
 - 63dbc56c-8abb-a9e1-b604-71b4a7cf698e
```

just the same, the following will work on multiple elements inside array brackets

```
msg: "{{ item.portnames | community.general.json_query('[*].nickname') | join(',') }}"
```

will get you

```
msg: abcdsto1p1,abcdsto1p2,abcdsto1p3,abcdsto1p4
```

...

Thats a couple use cases where we want the value returned as a string only.  We can filter with `join()`

Also thanks to @β.εηοιτ.βε for the tip.